# Search for a specific entry in ldap

Tags: ldap, ldap-query, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I am trying to search an entry on ldap based on the name of the same entry.

The search entries that I am getting are similar to this one:

```
CN=nameOfTheUser,OU=firstGroupName,...,DC=domain1,DC=domain2
```

What I want to do is filter my search to just show the entry with that name because currently I´m getting all of the entries:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(ldapConfig.getBaseDn(), SearchScope.SUB,
                 Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectClass", "person"));
```

I'm using ldap unboundid with springboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find "CN=nameOfTheUser,OU=firstGroupName,...,DC=domain1,DC=domain2" or any entry you know the DN is correct, you need something like:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("CN=nameOfTheUser,OU=firstGroupName,...,DC=domain1,DC=domain2", SearchScope.BASE, Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectClass", "person"));
```

You should also consider a READ similar to:

```
LDAPConnection.read("CN=nameOfTheUser,OU=firstGroupName,...,DC=domain1,DC=domain2",
             java.lang.String[], LDAPSearchConstraints)
```

If you need to find the entry, then a search request similar to:

```
Filter andFilter = new Filter.createANDFilter(
                    Filter.createEqualityFilter("objectClass", "person"),
                    Filter.createEqualityFilter("cn", "nameOfTheUser"));

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("new SearchRequest(ldapConfig.getBaseDn()", SearchScope.BASE, andFilter);
```

-jim

Comment: But can i find the entry just with the nameOfTheUser?

Comment: Updated answer based on clarification.